# On vue how to make a Edit function

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Im doing my first CRUD with Vue - Laravel, i did a Add function that works fine but my Edit button is doing another Add function.
(I get the alert from updateDespesa alert("Usuário Alterado!");)

My Frontend:

```
async updateDespesa(despesa) {
  const response = await axios
    .put("api/despesas/" + despesa, {

       des: this.despesa.des,
      valr: this.despesa.valr,
      vencc: this.despesa.vencc,
      stt: this.despesa.stt,
      emiss: this.despesa.emiss,
    })

    .then((response) => {

      this.despesa.id = "";
      this.despesa.valr = "";
      this.despesa.stt = "";
      this.despesa.vencc = "";
      this.despesa.emiss = "";
      this.getDespesa();
  if(despesa){
      alert("Usuário Alterado!");
  }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
},
```

My Backend:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    if ($id == 0) {
        $despesa = new Despesa;
        $despesa->create($request->all());
    }
    else {
        $despesa = Despesa::findOrFail($id);
        $despesa->fill($request->all())->save();
    }

    //$despesa->update($request->all());

    return response()->json('Sucess');
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65063931/how-to-make-a-edit-after-making-the-create this discussion still hasn't solved your problems?

Comment: No not yet, i solved the backend(now im getting and sending) but im not changing anything in my frontend. I think its because of my updateDespesa()

Answer (score 1):

In your backend, try update this and see

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    if ($id == 0) {
        $despesa = new Despesa;
        $despesa->create($request->all());
    }
    else {
        $despesa = Despesa::findOrFail($id);
        $despesa->fill($request->all())->save();
    }

    //$despesa->update($request->all());

    return response()->json('Sucess');
}
```

and also please check the `Despesa` Model has declared the input fields in `protected $fillable`

Comment: Now its working the same way "addDespesa" does, creating another one. But im getting the       alert("Usuário Alterado!"); from the "updateDespesa"

Comment: I edit the post with the new frontend/backend functions

Answer (score 0):

```
async updateDespesa(despesa) {
  const response = await axios
    .put("api/despesas/" + despesa, {
        ...
    })
    .then((response) => {


      // add this line, to check only alert when id is not null
      // so that it only alert when update
      if(despesa){
          alert("Usuário Alterado!");
      }


      ....
      
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
},
```

Comment: I did, im still getting the alert("Usuário Alterado!");

Comment: I used a console.log(response.data); after .then, im getting "Sucess" message from the backend update()

Comment: when you want to `alert("Usuário Alterado!");` ? when update or insert ?